# Python self decryption script, as mean of obfuscation

Tags: encryption, python, obfuscation

I have a software with an embedded python interpreter. The software can open upon startup a given `.py` script and execute it. Let's assume that in my python environment I can't open other files, and I can't use external tools like `Cython`

I want to obfuscate the script. My only demand is that the `payload` part of the file (my custom business logic) could not be opened in a text editor and plain-text read.

I could imagine the flow of the script will be de-obfuscation/decryption of a payload, that resides within the `.py` file as the first step and then executing it.

I can store within the script any encryption key, and I don't care that the decryption part will be visible and that it can be easily reproduced.

Any ideas how can I make that happen?

Comment: so basically you are writing a malware and you want people to help you.

Comment: If I wanted to write a malware, I wouldn't write it in python, and I would really care about the chance of it to be decrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar on the past, here is the idea you need to carry:

1. You create the python script that you want to execute and obfuscate:

   ```
   print('Some string')
   ```
2. Another script opens the previous script, encrypts the content and `base64` the encryption, and finally put in a variable like:

   ```
   text = "cHJpbnQoJ1NvbWUgc3RyaW5nJyk="
   ```
3. On another python file, you stick the text variable and a routine for decryption and decode the base64.
4. Use the method `eval()` for execute the previous decrypted and decoded string.

This is not perfect but at least you have something to play with and explore.